# Javascript cannot be loaded in time

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm running a flask web app and i getting an error like this:
**get (some js source) net::err_invalid_http_response**

But the problem is when I trying to get the page the scripts that not working are
different, sometimes all the scripts are working.

When I putting the scripts on the head of html it's loading better but still not all the scripts are working, but when I slowing down the internet to 3G in devtools all the scripts are running

I don't know what to do with it and I couldn't find nothing about it.

Im am using the standard script markup in html: `<script src="some/js"></script>`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the **type** attribute to the script tag and all start
working so the code looks like that:
`<script type="text/javascript src="js/source"></script>`